# Performance of running code in stani python editor vs IDLE/terminal/gvim

Tags: python, performance

Am just curious and wondering why it takes longer for python code to execute when run from inside Stani Python Editor in comparison to when run from IDLE or the terminal or even inside gvim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPE has an object explorer, and debugger. Maybe these slow things down a bit.